# c# how to end streamreader

Tags: c#, streamreader

I am doing a project Windows form for assignment in Uni, I want to search an already created text file to match a first name and last name then write some additional information if the name and last name exist. I have the code constructed and showing no errors, however when I run and attempt to add information I am being provided with an error which essentially says the next process (Streamreader writer can not access the file as it is already in use by another process) I assume this process is streamreader, I have tried to code it to stop reading to no avail. I am in my first 3 months learning coding and would appreciate some assistance if possible, I have put a snippet of my code below.

```
//check if there is a file with that name
        if (File.Exists(sFile))
        {

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sFile))
            {
                //while there is more data to read
                while (sr.Peek() != -1)
                {
                    //read first name and last name
                    sFirstName = sr.ReadLine();
                    sLastName = sr.ReadLine();
                }
                {
                    //does this name match?
                    if (sFirstName + sLastName == txtSearchName.Text)

                        sr.Close();
                }

                //Process write to file
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sFile, true))

                        {
                            sw.WriteLine("First Name:" + sFirstName);
                            sw.WriteLine("Last Name:" + sLastName);
                            sw.WriteLine("Gender:" + sGender);
                        }
```

Comment: Where is the closing bracket for your StreamReader. The using directive will dispose of the streamreader and release its lock on the file, but it looks as if you're not closing it until after you open the writer?

Comment: Read your input file, write to a temp file, then crush your input file with your temp file.

Comment: Are you sure this part of your code is executed? Cause it seems you are trying to read and write to the same file, at the same time. (Seems like a terrible idea)

Comment: Are you trying to append the additional data to the end of the same file or to the end of the line the name appears on?

Answer (score 1):

You are using your writer inside the reader, using the same file.
A using disposes the object inside it, after the closing curly braces.

```
 using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("foo")){
 //... some stuff
   using(Streamwriter writer = new StreamWriter("foo")){
   }
 }
```

Do it like so :

```
 using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("foo")){
 //... some stuff 
 }

 using(Streamwriter writer = new StreamWriter("foo")){
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment regarding the using statement. 
Rearrange to the below. I've tested locally and it seems to work.

```
   using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sfile))
   {
        //while there is more data to read
        while (sr.Peek() != -1)
        {
            //read first name and last name
           sFirstName = sr.ReadLine();
           sLastName = sr.ReadLine();

             //does this name match?
            if (sFirstName + sLastName == txtSearchName.Text)
                break;
        }
     }

    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sfile, true))
    {
        sw.WriteLine("First Name:" + sFirstName);
        sw.WriteLine("Last Name:" + sLastName);
        sw.WriteLine("Gender:" + sGender);
    }
```

I've replaced the sr.Close with a break statement to exit out. Closing the reader causes the subsequent peek to error as it's closed.

Also, I've noticed that you are not setting gender? unless its set elsewhere.
hope that helps

Comment: Hi Guys thanks so much for the assistance, I've removed  gender as it is no longer required, I have still an issue when using this code provided I get an error related to break; "No enclosing loop out of which to break or continue"??

Comment: Odd.. still works for me.. are you sure you've not got the break; statement outside of the while's brackets { } ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use FileStream. It gives you many options to work with file:

```
var fileStream = new FileStream("FileName", FileMode.Open,
 FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);


var fileStream = new FileStream("fileName", FileMode.Open, 
FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want/need. You can't append to a file the way you are trying to do it. Instead you'll want to read your input file, and write a temp file as you are reading through. And, whenever your line matches your requirements, then you can write the line with your modifications.

```
        string inputFile = "C:\\temp\\StreamWriterSample.txt";
        string tempFile = "C:\\temp\\StreamWriterSampleTemp.txt";

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(tempFile))//get a writer ready
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(inputFile))//get a reader ready
            {
                string currentLine = string.Empty;
                while ((currentLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (currentLine.Contains("Clients"))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(currentLine + " modified");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(currentLine);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //now lets crush the old file with the new file
        File.Copy(tempFile, inputFile, true);
```

Comment: I have a windows form which allows the input of a clients details in 6 lines of input written to a file. I have another part of the form containing check boxes  for exercise minutes carried out on different machines, I have a search box and a button, I am trying to search the current file for the first name and last name of a client "Name entered in search box" if it exists then append the new minutes information.  There is a radio button to select the day the activity was carried out. So the file needs to be appended to or the new lines added without overwriting . What changes do I need?

Comment: You need to completely rethink your approach and use a database, or an XML file at the very least. Reading and re-writting text file as if it was a database will perform very poorly in comparison. Though, to make my code work in your scenario you just have to fiddle with the if statement. But you have 3 lines to modify... Either you run the search for the 3 separate elements, or you will run it once and assume that if you find first name, that the next 2 lines are inevitably last name and gender. In either case, you'll end up re-writing your _database_ every time you make an update.